# Get the penny cost from SKTransaction iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

Hi I'm trying to do some server integration with my IAPs in my iOS app. The params for what I'm sending to the server require: transaction_ID, product_ID, and pennyCost.

The first two were easy enough to figure out but I can't find the cost. I do have some NSData for the receipt but I can't figure out how to get that into any form I can use. This is my code so far.

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
 NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

 purchaseComplete = 2;

 NSString *transaction_key = transaction.transactionIdentifier;
 NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
 NSNumber *pennyCost = transaction.payment.product.pennyCost;

 NSData *rec = [self receiptForPaymentTransaction:transaction];


}
```

The transaction.payment.product.pennyCost line is invalid.

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: The price is part of the `SKProduct` used to create the `SKPayment` you sent.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to the product in the completeTransaction as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SeanCalkins that's correct.  If you want to capture the cost of an IAP you must do so when you submit the purchase request.  You can use the `SKProduct` from the `SKTransaction` to retrieve the *current price* of that product, but this may not be the price that applied when the purchase was made

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SKPayment` doesn't have a price, oddly enough. The price is defined on the `SKProduct` after retrieving the product using an `SKProductRequest`.

What you need to do is keep a reference to the `SKProduct` instances returned from the `SKProductRequest`. Once you submit a payment to the `SKPaymentQueue` and you get back your response, use the `productId` of the `SKPayment` to find the matching `SKProduct`.

Now it's possible that you will receive a payment transaction later, after your app has been restarted. In that case, you will have to make a new `SKProductRequest` to get the `SKProduct` so you can get the price.

The bad part about all of this is that the price you get for the product could different from what the user is actually charged since you might update the product's pricing in between the time you received the payment transaction and the time you request the product info.